# I am trying to import Json to firebase and getting the invalid json exception

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know we cannot use ascii 0-31 and 127 as key in firebase and I am pretty sure there is no such key here in json can someone help me with this.

```
{   
    "HW_Key_Prog": "    FORD-K2",
        "HW_Remote_Prog": "",
        "HW_Misc_Prog": "FORD-B",
        "TKOSDD_System": " PATS 5 CAN",
        "TKOSDD_SDD_Adapter": "No",
        "TKOSDD_SDD_Cable": "   00(D922876ZR",
        "TKOSDD_TKO_Cable": "   00(D922876ZR"

}
```

Comment: When you say you're trying to import JSON, are you importing from the console? I just imported your JSON to a Firebase project from the console and it worked.

Comment: yes jen i am importing through console,yesterday it was throwing error i could upload it today this is a subset of the columns i thought problem was with this columns later i figured that i  could upload this not the whole file with 1000 rows in it i am still not sure why it is throwing the error for sure there is no problem with the keys because i tested by uploading just the first row, but when i am trying to insert the 1000 rows all together within json file it is throwing the error what might be the reason

Answer (score 0):

i was scratching my head with this issue and it might be two reasons.

1) your keys having ascii charecter 0-31 , 127 because firebase doesnot take this charecters as keys so make sure there are none of these charecters in your key.

2) problem with your json format use https://jsonformatter.org/ to validate the json data

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are constructing the JSON document with code that doesn't follow the standard. If it is a library, please report the bug. If not, why not use a library?

String:

> Characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus,
> and the control characters (U+0000    through U+001F)
> —[RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)

You have U+0009 characters that need to be escaped as "\t".